Nothing happens after executing an SQL command with python
This is my code:
import mysql.connector 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', 
                        database='glabo', 
                        user='root', 
                        password='.........') 
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO orders (o_userid, o_labo, o_jour, o_heure) SELECT users.user_id, labos.l_id, jours.j_id, heures.h_id FROM users, labos, jours, heures WHERE users.user_name = 'Kbayad' AND labos.l_nom = 'LABO 1' AND jours.j_jour = 'Mardi' AND heures.h_heure = '10-12';")

After running this python code, I don't get any error but nothing changes in the database

maybe a commit?

What does it mean?

Are you sure the INSERT's SELECT returns any data? Try INSERT with VALUES instead.

Why do you use a cursor to INSERT?

Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.  (Not the answer, but still a good advice.)

check any tutorial, for ex here and search for "commit"

@jarlh yes it's works in mysql + thx i will try to use JOIN

this is probably because MySQL transactions in Python are not auto-committed.
in MySQL, when you execute a query that modifies data (like INSERT), those changes are not automatically saved (or "committed") to the database.
you need to explicitly tell the database to save those changes by using the commit() method.
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost', 
    database='glabo', 
    user='root', 
    password='.........'
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO orders (o_userid, o_labo, o_jour, o_heure) 
    SELECT users.user_id, labos.l_id, jours.j_id, heures.h_id 
    FROM users, labos, jours, heures 
    WHERE users.user_name = 'Kbayad' 
    AND labos.l_nom = 'LABO 1' 
    AND jours.j_jour = 'Mardi' 
    AND heures.h_heure = '10-12';
""")

mydb.commit()
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()


OOH THANKS IT'S WORKING NOW  THANK YOU A LOT!
